# Wamp and Php extension one click enable

Tags: php, wamp, php-extension

Please tell me how to enable all these extension all at once. They are creating a lot of problem.

[image]

I want to enable all of them by just one click.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1) check them all one by one

2) go to php.ini uncomment them.

3) or thrught ini_set() in php file

For first two you need to restart your apache server.

Answer (score 0):

FoThey are all installed. You only have to check the ones you want, but there is no way you can do it in one click ...